# Parse issue while specifying class type argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I'm very new to obj-c and have next problem:
I have two classes: Main and Second (Second isn't child of Main), and I want to declare a method in Main class that gets as argument Second class object. It looks like this:

```
#import "CCNode.h"
#import "Second.h"

@interface Main : CCNode

-(void)buyFor:(int)price object:(Second *) obj;

@end
```

And Xcode gives parse issue while parsing (Second *), it don't gets what type of object i want to be as argument. 
So if you need more information about classes/project please tell me.

Second.h

```
#import "CCNode.h"

@interface Second : CCNode

@property int price;
```

Second.m

```
#import "Second.h"
#import "Main.h"

@implementation Second{
    Main *_main;
}
-(void)tap{
    NSLog(@"Buy");
    [_main buyObject:self forPrice:_price];
}
```

Comment: Please include Second.h, .m code.

Comment: Thanks to p4sh4, using @class instead of importing headers helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What issue exactly do does Xcode give you? The code looks fine on first glance. Do you have the "Second.h" and "Second.m" files in your project?

A couple of other tips:

- It's not very good practice to import headers into headers. Use the @class keyword in the Main.h header to do a forward declaration and import "Second.h" in the "Main.m" implementation file. I think you should try this and see if the error happens again.
- Your method name isn't really correct in an Objective-C way. Something like `-(void)buyObject:(Second *)obj forPrice:(int)price` would be more correct, with the method name being more of an actual sentence.